# Is it possible to check how much RAM memory was on notebook before some time?

Tags: memory, logging

i have interesting issue. I put dead notebook into service and after some time they return it back to me fixed. But they didnt put back one 4GB memory module, so instead of 2x 4GB modules i have only one. Is there any way, how to prove that i have 2 modules in notebook? Not only one? Or how much memory was there? Probably so hardware log or etc?

Comment: your best bet is to look application logs. ps. : this is why you shouldn't trust any service except official ones.

Comment: Probably unlikely in a notebook, but the BIOS may log changes in memory size.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Where can I find evidence of changes in the amount of RAM installed on a windows machine?](http://superuser.com/questions/687924/where-can-i-find-evidence-of-changes-in-the-amount-of-ram-installed-on-a-windows)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show historic hardware changes in windows 7](http://superuser.com/questions/907391/show-historic-hardware-changes-in-windows-7)